# How do I transport a foldable lawn chair via Airline baggage?

Tags: luggage, airlines, singapore-airlines

I have a 38 inch tall foldable chair - [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00339C3RI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00339C3RI)
which doesn't fit in my luggage.

I am traveling by Singapore Airlines, and while their Baggage allowance section (http://www.singaporeair.com/jsp/cms/en_UK/travel_information/baggage-allowance.jsp) talks about wheelchairs & sports equipment. I can't seem to find much on transporting a regular oversized piece of luggage.

What would be the cheapest/best option to transport it in airline baggage? Is there any other option?

Comment: Personally I'd ship it or just buy one at the destination.

Answer (score 5):

I see no reason they will not handle it as normal checked baggage -- of course if you're travelling to the US you'll be limited to two pieces of checked baggage, if not you'll be limited by weight. Here's the [Singapore Airlines](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/travel-information/baggage-allowances/) baggage page (which you've probably already seen).

Assuming you're flying from/to the US and taking only one other suitcase I would think you're under the size limit:

> **Dimensions (Economy)**
>
> Sum of length, width, height of i) each piece not exceeding 158cm (62in) and 
>   ii)  two pieces not exceeding 273cm (107in)

So as long as your suitcase is less than 69in in it's longest direction I think you're fine. Check the total weight as well.

You will have to collect it from a special conveyor, probably.

Alternatively, phone the airline's customer services on use the online forms from [this page](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/feedback-enquiry/).